# How to change the exponent character's case for R's exponential notation convention

Tags: r, csv, number-formatting

Simple question about controlling the notation of how R prints the exponent character. The default appears to be lowercase 'e' but I'd actually like uppercase 'E' for the purposes of writing a data frame to a CSV file that won't alter columns that will be diff'd with other CSV files whose exponent character holds the upper case convention.

DEFAULT R OPTIONS

```
> 10^100
[1] 1e+100
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
> 10^100
[1] 1E+100
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatC

```
> formatC(10^100,digits = 2,format = "E")
[1] "1.00E+100"

gsub("e","E",formatC(x = 10^100))
[1] "1E+100"
```

Comment: I gave the 10^100 as an example of the output I was going for, but in reality I'm dumping a whole dataframe to file via write.csv(). I was hoping that there might be a global option for toggling this sort of behavior. It's true however that I could resort to my own formatting using the methods you provided.

Comment: If you are exporting as string just apply the function to all the rows of the columns you are trying to convert. But, the original notation when you write as csv it exports as a numeric vector anyway.